# If $f$ has integral on $[a,b]$ and continuous at $x_0∈[a,b]$ then $F$ has derivative at point $x_0$ and $F'(x_0)=f(x_0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, indefinite-integrals, riemann-integration

Suppose that $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. Let

$$F(x)=\int_{a}^xf(t)dt, \quad a\leq x \leq b.$$

If $f$ is continuous at $x_0 \in [a,b]$ then $F$ has derivative at $x_0$ and $F^\prime(x_0)=f(x_0)$.

This is the proof from my book:
$$
F(x_0  + \Delta x) - F(x_0 ) = \int_a^{x_0  + \Delta x} {f(t)dt}  - \int_a^{x_0 } {f(t)dt}  = \int_{x_0 }^{x_0  + \Delta x} {f(t)dt} .
$$
From this $$\frac{F(x_0+\Delta x)-F(x_0)}{\Delta x}-f(x_0)=\frac{1}{\Delta x}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\Delta x}[{f(t)-f(x_0)}]dt.$$

Can you please help how we got this? Shouldn't it be $ \frac{1}{\Delta x}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\Delta x}[{f(t)-f(x_0)\Delta x}]dt$?

Comment: The Weierstrass function is continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere.

Comment: @OliverKayende What that have to do with my question? I am asking why there is no $\triangle x$ multiplied $f(x_0)$.

Comment: Sorry I edited.

Comment: $$
\int_{x_0 }^{x_0  + \Delta x } {f(x_0 )dt}  = f(x_0 )\int_{x_0 }^{x_0  + \Delta x} {1dt}  = f(x_0 )(x_0  + \Delta x - x_0 ) = f(x_0 )\Delta x
$$

Comment: @Gary Thank you very much!